# Advanced search in data tables using PHP

Tags: php, mysqli, datatable, datatables

I've created a data table using the following codes :-

main.php - it contain the script to call data table and the php script which is fetching the data from sql database

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Data Table | Server Side | Basic | Zero Level</title>
</head>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">

<body>

<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th><th>Gender</th><th>Age</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th><th>Gender</th><th>Age</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>

</body>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.2/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.2/js/buttons.flash.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.36/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.36/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.2/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.2/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#example').DataTable( {
            dom: 'Bfrtip',
            buttons: [
                'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
            ],
            "bProcessing": true,
            "sAjaxSource": "dtServerSideBasicScript.php",
            "aoColumns": [{
                mData: 'name','gender','age'
            }]
        } );
    } );
</script>

</html>
```

and dtServerSideBasicScript.php - It is the script which is fetching the data from sql server :-

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","work");
$sql = "SELECT name,gender,age from test ";
$r = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$result = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r)){
    array_push($result,array(
        "name"=>$row['name'],"gender"=>$row['gender'],"age"=>$row['age']
    ));
}
echo json_encode(array('data'=>$result));?>
```

Now, I've to apply advance filter section above the data table, which can be a form that consist of following fields - a name input, an age range input and a gender select input field. And on submission of this form the relevant search result should be displayed in the data table.

Comment: `header('Content-Type: application/json');` before you do the `echo`. Not your problem, but something you should be doing.

Comment: You need to let us know what your problem is, what have you tried?

Comment: Unless the example is wrong, I'd expect this to return a 500 internal server error due to `$row['age]` which doesn't close off the `age` part - it should be `$row['age']`.  If that's not the issue, can you correct the issues in the example and outline the error

Comment: @delboy1978uk The above code is running perfectly. But now I've add an advanced filter option in it using PHP.

Comment: @gabe3886 that's just a typo. The above script is working well. But now I want to modify it to add an advance fiter option in it using PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me give you example for search by name you can do same for other search field also.

add below input tag in your html for search field

```
<input type="text" name="user_name" id="user_name" />
```

now change your script as per below,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
                    var table=$('#example').DataTable( {
                        dom: 'Bfrtip',
                        buttons: [
                            'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
                        ],
                        "bProcessing": true,
                        "ajax": {
                               url: "dtServerSideBasicScript.php",
                               data: function (d) {

                                   d.user_name = function () {

                                     return $("#user_name").val();
                                   };
                               },
                          },

                        "aoColumns": [{
                            mData: 'name','gender','age'
                        }]
                    } );

                 $('#user_name').keyup(function () {
                    table.draw();
                 });
    });
</script>
```

on server side you will get user_name parameter in $_GET, like $_GET['user_name']. then you can use that value in your sql query with like.

Same way you can implement the age range and gender selection.

Comment: on clicking the search button it is redirecting to a page and showing this result - {"data":[{"name":"ankur"}]} - which is not what i desired. Please help!

Comment: which search button? there is no need of search button. can you please give us more details.

Comment: Okay, I got your point. But then how will I display the result of that query in data table?

Comment: result will append by datatable in your tbody of table. that all will done in background by ajax call. It is good if you check documentation of datatable with ajax for better idea how it works.